# Can FormBuilder be used in a Service class to build forms not connected to an Entity class?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to use Symfony2's FormBuilder Component to build dynamic forms within a service class.  However, these forms will not be linked to any entities immediately (so I don't think the Form Class service type would apply.)

I need to ask our users a series of questions with a myriad of outcomes depending on how the questions are answered.(For example: Do you like cheesecake?  If yes, the user will be directed to another form asking what kind of cheescake; if no, ask if you like ice cream.. etc.)  To do this I created a Dialoguer service which is instantiated with the FormFactory service.  From services.yml:

```
dialoguer:
    class: My\MainBundle\Services\Dialoguer    
    arguments: ['@forms.factory']
```

Each step of the dialog process is handled by a different dialogue class - all of which are children of an AbstractDialogue class.  The dialoguer service looks at data that has already been answered and finds the appropriate dialog to ask next.

The dialoguer service passes the @forms.factory service to the appropriate dialog class, in this case Start:

```
namespace My\MainBundle\Services\Dialoguer\Individual;

use My\MainBundle\Services\Dialoguer\AbstractDialogue as AbstractDialogue;

class Start extends AbstractDialogue
{
    static $stem = 'check_registration';    
    protected $fields = array(
        'over_thirtyfive' => array(
        'type' => 'choice',
        'options' => array( 
            'label' => 'Are you over 35?', 
            'choices'=>array('yes'=>'Yes','no'=>'No'), 
            'expanded'=> true, 
            'multiple'=>false 
            )
        )
    );
....

function __construct( $formFactory )
{
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
}
```

From the parent, AbstractDialogue class, the get_form method goes through each field and adds it the form based on the specifications above.

```
public function get_form( $form_data = array() )
{       
    $defaults = array_merge( $this->defaults, $form_data );

    $builder = $this->formFactory->create();
    $builder->setData( $defaults );
    foreach( $this->fields as $field => $type_ar )
    {
        $builder = $builder->add( $field, $type_ar['type'], $type_ar['options'] );
    }
    //return $builder->getForm();
    return $builder;
}
```

And, finally in the controller class:

```
$dialogue = $this->get('dialoguer')->process($request, 'Individual');
$form = $dialogue->get_form()->getView();
$args = compact('form');
return $this->render("MyMainBundle:Forms:process_app.form.html.twig", $args);
```

Finally, here's the issue:
Above, my get_form method passes a Symfony\Component\Form\Form instance, which doesn't have the getView method - so it throws an error.

What do I need to do get a form view using this non-traditional method of creating a form?
(Or is this not going to work?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a typo in my Controller that prevented the form from accessing the View.  'getView' should be changed to 'createView'.  Whoops.

I also made a change to my service, changing '$this->formFactory->create()' to '$this->formFactory->createBuilder();'

For folks in the future, I'll walk through the script in the service class and the accompanying apis:

```
public function get_form( $form_data = array() )
{       
$defaults = array_merge( $this->defaults, $form_data );

$builder = $this->formFactory->createBuilder();
```

As I mentioned in the original post - $this->formFactory is made available to my class by importing '@form.factory' through my service configuration. That's createBuilder instantiates an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder ~ http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html

```
$builder->setData( $defaults );
foreach( $this->fields as $field => $type_ar )
{
    $builder = $builder->add( $field, $type_ar['type'], $type_ar['options'] );
}
return $builder->getForm();
}
```

The getForm method instantiates an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form ~ http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html

And then in my Controller -

```
$form = $dialogue->get_form()->createView();
```

The createView method creates an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView which can the be rendered in Twig:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

It works.